# Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 1

Tags: matlab

I wanted to convert anonymous function to a symbolic function.

I have something like

```
f = @(x)4*(3/4*pi-x(1))-7*x(3)
g = sym(f)
```

but I always get Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 1. How to fix this?

My x has usually size 8,1 but that shouldn't be relevant i guess
Do I need to convert my x to sym as well or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your anonymous function `f`, `x` is defined to have minimum three indices and hence `sym(f)` cannot be used to convert it to `sym`.

Instead, you can call `f` with a symbolic variable `x` of size 1x3 like this:

```
g = f(sym('x',[1,3]));
```

which gives:

```
>> g
g =
 3*pi - 7*x3 - 4*x1
```

Comment: Hey, thank you this helped me but now when I want to use that in another function I get a new problem. I have g = f(sym('x',[1,8])); and I also want to define my x as symbolic so I used symbolic_x = sym(x); since I want to use to calculate jacobian  df = simplify(jacobian(symbolic_cbf, symbolic_x)); but get Invalid argument at position 2. Argument must be a variable, a symfun without a formula, or a symfun
whose formula is a variable. (line with df=...), can you help me with this one?

Comment: I use [1,8] because I have 8 'variables' in my x, above function is just partial example of my f function.

Comment: Define `x` like this: `x= sym('x',[1,8]);`  Please see the example in the doc: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html#d123e288220 . And then you can do `g=f(x);` and take jacobian

Comment: Hey, I have another question. Now I want to go back to the function handle, so I have   dcbf = simplify(jacobian(symbolic_cbf, symbolic_x));
    lf_cbf_ = dcbf * f_; and when i want to convert i use lf_cbf = matlabFunction(lf_cbf_, 'vars', {x}) but always get The value of 'Vars' is invalid. 'Vars' value must be a character vector, a 1-dimensional cell array of character
vectors, a 1-dimensional cell array of symbolic variables or arrays of symbolic variables, or an array of symbolic
variables. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have a new question